# (Swift) extension of S<S<P>> where S is a generic structure and P is a type-constrained protocol

Tags: swift, generics

Given these types:

```swift
struct S<T> {...}
protocol P { associatedtype A ... }
```

I want something like this:

```swift
extension S<S<T>> where T:P { ... }
```

where the first `S` has the type parameter of another `S` and the second has the type parameter of some `P`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift doesn't support this syntax currently (see [SR-3716](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3716)). You need to attach the constraint to each extension method directly:

```
extension S {
    func f<U>() where T == S<U>, U: P {}
}
```

With that in place, you'll be able to call `f()` for some values, but not others:

```
extension String: P {
    public typealias A = Int
}

S<Int>().f()        // Fails
S<S<Int>>().f()     // Fails
S<String>().f()     // Fails
S<S<String>>().f()  // Succeed
```

Unfortunately, autocomplete will still offer `f()` in places it's not allowed, and the diagnostic is not ideal:

```
Generic parameter 'U' could not be inferred
Instance method 'f()' requires the types 'Int' and 'S<U>' be equivalent
```

I believe there is work going on to improve the developer experience around this, but the compiler will enforce it.